# Is there a way for Lightroom to export without changing the ppi?

Tags: photo-editing, dpi, ppi, adobe-lightroom

Currently I am creating .psd images "to scale" by changing the ppi so that 1mm = 1mm. This way I can drop the image in InDesign and it will print at the actual size. I cannot however find a way for Lightroom to export a jpg without altering the ppi, so I instead have to open it with photoshop again and export it there.

Am I missing something, or does Lightroom have to set the resolution every time?

Right now, I'm using lightroom more for it's cataloging than it's editing.
My workflow is:
1. Shoot product with green-screen and ruler.
2. Make basic adjustments in Lightroom and add keywords, titles...
3. Export to .psd (100dpi) to mask out background and more touchups.
4. Use ruler measurements to calculate dpi for "scale".  Since image is at 100dpi, if 1cm on the "ruler" reads 186.2mm (example) I change the dpi to 1862. Now 1cm = 1cm.
5. Back in Lightroom I would like to export the .psd to various jpgs, but need 1 that retains the 1862dpi (which varies).

Comment: What happens to the dpi flag when you export the file as TIFF?

Comment: Good thinking, but both .tiff and .jpg export adhere to the ppi resolution under image size, regardless of not resizing the image. There is no way to leave that field blank either. :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you meant that lightroom alters the PPI upon export. Personally, I would place a 1cm scale marker somewhere along the edges of the image and use that to size the content in inDesign.

Comment: I don't know that I'm following your math converting millimeters to 'per inch' measurements. What DPI are you ultimate trying to print at? There is no direct hard correlation between DPI and 'actual size'. A 1" image at 100dpi will print the same size as a 1" image at 1000dpi.

Comment: FWIW, you might be better off asking this in photography.se

Answer (score 1):

Am i correct that you want to edit jpeg images in Lightroom which already contain resolution information? In this case afaik you have to set the resolution for each file as you already stated in your question.

Lightroom is designed to manage and edit photos from digital cameras which do not have inherent resolution information (it would not make sense). Exporting images is the first time the physical size of the image comes into play.

E.g. if you have a 12MP camera (~4300*2800) and use the Lightroom default setting of 240ppi, images exported from Lightroom will appear of ~18x12inch in InDesign.

Comment: Right now, I'm using lightroom more for it's cataloging than it's editing.  

My workflow is:  

1. Shoot product with green-screen and ruler.  
2. Make basic adjustments in Lightroom and add keywords, titles...  
3. Export to .psd (100dpi) to mask out background and more touchups.  
4. Use ruler measurements to calculate dpi for "scale".  Since image is at 100dpi, if 1cm on the "ruler" reads 186.2mm (example) I change the dpi to 1862. Now 1cm = 1cm.  
5. Back in Lightroom I would like to export the .psd to various jpgs, but need 1 that retains the 1862dpi (which varies).

Comment: @user1177301 why are you exporting at 100dpi? That's an incredibly low resolution for print work.